# Can I change button text as input text value changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this very simple form:

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <form>
      <input type="text" value="" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().change(this)" />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" name="button1" value="{{text}}" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this JS:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.text = "New";
  $scope.change = function (element) {
    $scope.text = element.value;
    $scope.$apply();
  }
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsoegijono/d28L8bc9/)

Currently, the button `value` is updated when I leave the text field. How can I change the button `value` as user is typing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to reinvent the wheel, just use [`ng-model`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) directive:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="text" />
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/d28L8bc9/1/

Comment: Follow up: If I want to change the button label ONLY IF text.length > 3, is it an easy edit?

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <form>
      <input type="text" value="" ng-model="text" />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" name="button1" value="{{text}}" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.text = "New";
}
```